# Failed to complete Gradle execution.Cause: Unknown command-line option '-f'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am on 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 as demanded by Android sdk, I have set command '-force-32bit' (without quotes) in command line options under Settings>Compiler>Command Line Options in Android Studio

It was all working fine and I didn't change anything but out of nowhere i  start getting this error:

`Failed to complete Gradle execution.Cause: Unknown command-line option '-f'`

I Searched internet but  couldn't find a solution

Comment: @divanov- Not a duplicate,in my case command-line is not accepting a valid command which I do need to run the emulator on 32 bit linux

Comment: `-force-32bit` is Android emulator option, not compiler option, so this is not valid command and Gradle just reports this.